# Localize and iOS application with 2 targets using different languages. App store details

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store-connect

I've already read a lot of answers on Stackoverflow on the topic but I've not found the right answer. 
I'm working on an App that has 2 targets and for these targets I have different localizations.

- Target A has English, French and Italian
- Target B has English, Japanese and Spanish

So the Project is localized for all the languages but I've removed the useless langs file and folders for the targets. For example, I've removed folder `jp.lproj` and `es.lproj` from `Target A` and folders `fr.lproj` and `it.lproj` from `Target B` (previously I've deselected the target membership for files that are not needed for a specific target).

What does define the `Languages` information stated in the App description on the App Store? Is this information automatically taken from the project info? If this is the case it will appear that my 2 targets support all the languages: en, it, es, fr, jp :(

I saw that from iTunesConnect I can manually set the localizations now... is this the element taken into account to define which languages to show on the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All information on the App Store (in your case metadata/app description) is handled via iTunes Connect. What "version" or rather language gets shown, depends on the user's language and country settings.

> Information that is localizable must be changed for each localization
>   individually by selecting the language from the dropdown.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW46